How to set PowerShell OutputType for a list of named properties
Consider this function which returns a table of string values, each row having two string properties with names DisplayName and DisplayVersion:
function Get-InstalledDotNetPacks{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param()
  Get-ItemProperty `
      -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*", `
            "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" |
       Where {$_.DisplayName -like '*.NET*'} |
       Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion |
       Sort -Property DisplayName
}

What can I do with OutType() to reveal the two property names that the function will return?

Easiest way would be to define a class that serves as a property bag and allows discovery of those two properties:
class DotNetPack {
    [string] $DisplayName
    [string] $DisplayVersion
}

Then you get rid of Select-Object, cause that one returns PSCustomObject, and replace it with instances of your class instead:
function Get-InstalledDotNetPacks {
    [OutputType([DotNetPack])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]] $Path = @(
            'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
            'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
        )
    )

    Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path |
        Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like '*.NET*' } |
        Sort-Object -Property DisplayName |
        ForEach-Object {
            [DotNetPack]@{
                DisplayName    = $_.DisplayName
                DisplayVersion = $_.DisplayVersion
            }
        }
}

And completion works fine after:


If you want to use OutputType(), then Santiago's answer will do it.
I am wondering if this would give you the information you want.
PS C:\> Get-ItemProperty `
>>       -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*", `
>>             "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" |
>>        Where {$_.DisplayName -like '*.NET*'} |
>>        Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion |
>>        Get-Member

   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name           MemberType   Definition
----           ----------   ----------
Equals         Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode    Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType        Method       type GetType()
ToString       Method       string ToString()
DisplayName    NoteProperty string DisplayName=Microsoft .NET AppHost Pack - 6.0.33 (x64_arm64)
DisplayVersion NoteProperty string DisplayVersion=48.132.18378

